# Bind Two Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, traits

I have two parallel class hierarchy, where the first hierarchy is for an API while the second is used in the model layer.
The same type has one representation(class) in each hierarchy and I want to 'bind' (more later) this two classes in order to use generics.

```
      API
     /   \
 ApiA     ApiB

     Model
     /   \
ModelA    ModelB
```

For instance, once this function

```
public string DoSomething<APIType> (APIType value) {
```

gets an APIType as argument (e.g. ApiB), I want to call the associated generic method that takes a ModelType as type argument (ModelB in this case).

I tried something similar to this:
    public string DoSomething (ApiType value) where ModelType: Model where ApiType : API

But I then discover that C# can't do partial inference, so this:

```
class ApiB : Api<ModelB> {}

ApiB obj;
DoSomething(obj)
```

can't work (both type arguments are required)

I tried to implement something similar to C++ traits but it did not work.
It would be possible to use only Type, but I am doing this in order to get the additional compiler checking.

I guess this is not a big problem, however I would like to know if someone knows a solution.

Comment: I feel that if your ApiA makes sense with ModelA only then it should subclass API<ModelA> with concrete model specifed, and should not be generic

Answer (score 1):

It's very complex question. Check this code, I've replaced `associated generic method` call with generic constructor of `List`. Coment if there is difference between what you questioned and what I understood from question.

```
class Program
{
    public class Model { }

    public class ModelB : Model { }

    public class Api<T> where T : Model
    {
        public List<T> CallGenericMethod()
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
    }

    public class ApiB: Api<ModelB> { }

    public static string DoSomething<T>(Api<T> a) where T : Model
    {
        var b = a.CallGenericMethod();
        return b.GetType().ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApiB a = new ApiB();
        Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(a));
    }
}
```

**Edit two types generic version**

```
public class Api<TApi, TModel> where TApi: Api<TApi, TModel> where TModel : Model
{
    public List<TModel> CallGenericMethod()
    {
        return new List<TModel>();
    }
}

public class ApiB: Api<ApiB, ModelB> { }

public static string DoSomething<TApi, TModel>(Api<TApi, TModel> a) where TApi : Api<TApi, TModel> where TModel: Model
{
    return new Dictionary<TApi, TModel>().GetType().ToString();
}
```

Comment: It does the job, however I will have to edit Api everytime I want to add a new method that use this the Model generic type, so it is not the best solution (it seems however that it is the only viable one in C#)

Comment: @Clynamen If in `DoSomething` you will call `new List<T>()` it will create `List<ModelB>` as well.

Comment: Earlier I did not realize you didn't use generic in DoSomething **for the APIType**, as in the question. I could  try to replace that and use plain inheritance like you did

Comment: @Clynamen It is possible to use both types, but a bit uglier.

Comment: yes unfortunately (that was I meant to say earlier about partial inference). By the way I would like to avoid that since it would make the code really messy (this would be used several times)